# Can the Garmin 520 be charged while riding?

Tags: bike-computer

I am looking to buy the Garmin 520 for some brevets but it only makes sense to do so if I can charge the device while riding. Does anyone know if this is possible?

I know that the usb port is in a funny place on the back of the device which will make charging difficult, but I just need to know if it is possible or if it will go into standby mode during charging.

I know that some models allow for charging while riding while others do not. I want to know if this model in particular does.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Garmin Edge 500/510 and 800/810 be charged while riding?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/15420/can-garmin-edge-500-510-and-800-810-be-charged-while-riding)

Comment: I believe the garmin goes into a "charging" mode when charging.  Its rated for dozens of hours of battery life - are you worried that it will run flat during your ride?

Comment: I am worried that it will die on a 20 hour ride and I won't be able to get a big portion of the data. Thanks!

Comment: @Criggie If he wants if for a Brevet it could be a 600km multiday ride, so yes it is likely to run flat

Comment: @changechange Fair enough.  Try it out - charge your device and then run it for as long as possible, to see how long it lasts.   Also consider using strava on a smartphone as well, as a separate backup system.  Most cellphones can charge off USB battery at the same time as being used.

Comment: As an alternative, consider one of Garmin's hiking models like the Dakota, Montana, or Oregon.  Some of them support using AAs that can be easily switched out, and a second set of batteries should be enough to get you through the full 20 hours.  They make a great bicycle handlebar mount.  Also, many models support Cadence (GPS only for speed) and HRM but it's a feature that Garmin doesn't advertise too much.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://forums.mtbr.com/gps-hrm-bike-computer/garmin-edge-520-a-980371.html) thread contains all the information you would ever want to know about the Edge 520.  The bottom of [Post #67](http://forums.mtbr.com/gps-hrm-bike-computer/garmin-edge-520-a-980371-3.html#post12197789) says that this is indeed possible.